# Authorize.net error: Gateway error: Unable to read response, or response is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

**I am having an issue with our Authorize.net payment gateway having issues. The payment processes it properly on our local computers using the same setup apparently.**

Our Setup:

- Magento 1.9.2.0
- Ubuntu 22.04 VPS on Interserver.net
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.6-FPM
- TLS 1.2
- Let's Encrypt SSL added

Error message via exception.log:

2023-10-18T21:26:37+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Gateway error: Unable to read response, or response is empty' in /var/www/jbcases-sites/jbcases-com-test/app/Mage.php